Name change on my US visa
I am currently in the US on a J1 visa. On my original passport, my full name was mistakenly entered in the surname section, leaving the first and given name fields blank. As a result, when I applied for my US visa, it was issued with 'FNU' (First Name Unknown) followed by my full name. I have since corrected my name in a new passport, with my first and last names properly split. I would like to know the procedure to update my name on the visa. Should I apply for a new visa, or is there another process I should follow?
